# How to float more than one <ul> inside a container?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I would like to have these unordered lists float side-by-side with each occupying  50% of the containing div, however I can only achieve that when the width of each `ul` is set to no more than 40%. This seems like a pretty simple styling situation, however I am new to this so I am probably missing something.

```
    <div class="middle">
      <ul id="filterbar">
        <li data-selection=1> Glucose Curve </li>
      </ul>
     <ul id="lookback">
       <li data-lookback=0> Today </li>
       <li data-lookback=999> Full History </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
```

CSS

```
.middle {
  width:50%;
  height:1500px;
}

ul {
  width:50%;
  height:100px;
  float:left;
  }

li {
  display:in-line;
  float:left;
  list-style:none;
  width:15%;
```

}

Comment: can you end your <div class="middle"> before people start talking about it :)

Comment: it's there when I go to edit it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Corrected Answer: Set the `margin`s and `padding` of the `<ul>` element to zero. See the answer by @Adam below for details.

Comment: @Adam is right, this was wrong. I tried deleting it, but couldn't because it was already accepted, so I edited it to reflect the correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the width of 50%, your UL's also have margin's and padding associated with them by default.

There's a lot of ways that I could tell you how to do this, but because your new I'm assuming you'll eventually read all about box-sizing, the importance of zeroing margins, checking what your elements actually look like in developer tools, etc. and just tell you this is what you are missing:

```
ul {
  width:50%;
  height:100px;
  float:left; 
  margin:0; padding:0;
  }
```

Contrary to the answer by @chopper, which is completely wrong, a percentage width of an element will always be calculated as a percentage of it's immediate parent element.

Comment: Thank you. That answer seemed wrong to me even with my limited understanding of box-sizing, because I have been using width relative to parent elsewhere without any problems. I guess I thought his answer might be relevant for ul's. Is it OK to upvote your answer having previously accepted an incorrect answer?

Comment: Also, your answer about ul's having default margins and padding is right on the money. This answered an unasked question of mine as to why a ul extended beyond its parent div. Once I set both to 0 as you suggested - problem fixed!

Comment: @Adam, thanks for clarifying. My bad - this was a misconception that I've held for a while. I guess you never stop learning. Even with something as basic as this :-/